In How many ways we can select four letters of the word FARIDABAD

Consider $4$ boxes, where each box contains $3$ red balls and $2$ blue balls. Assume that all $20$ balls are distinct. In how many different ways can $10$ balls be chosen from these $4$ boxes so that from each box atleast one red ball and one blue ball are chosen?

Solution:
Required number of ways = coefficient of $x^2$+coefficient of $xy$+ coefficent of $y^2$ in $(3x+3x^2+x^3)^4(2y+y^2)$, which is $21816$.

In How many ways we can select four letters of the word FARIDABAD

Solution:
Required number of ways is coefficient of $x^4$ in $(1+x+x^2+x^3)(1+x+x^2)(1+x)^4$ and which is $41$
My doubt: In first question they are considering two variables $x,y$ to solve this problem and in second question they are considering only one variable $x$. My doubt is how to explain someone when to take two variables and when to take only one variable? Also where can i find similar solution approach for 3 variables?

I think you can use just one variable $x$ in the first problem: Expanding the expression $(3x + 3x^2 + x^3)^4 (2x + x^2)$ will give you the same result (the coefficient of the $x^2$ term is $21816$).


To start with, you don't need both $x$ and $y$ because they are only placeholders for how many of each color of ball we choose.
For the first problem, written in full form for better understanding, just find the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in $\left[\left(\binom31x + \binom32x^2 + \binom33x^3\right)\left(\binom21x+\binom22x^2\right)\right]^4 = 21816$


For Faridabad, you already know how to obtain the answer. By the way, you should have written any four letters... instead of "the four letters of FARIDABAD"

If $3$ types are there, e.g. you want to find the number of ways to $\texttt{choose}$ $6$ beads from $3$ distinct white beads, $3$ distinct black beads, and $3$ distinct red beads $\texttt{without any restrictions}$, (which means $0$ of a type allowed) this time written in shorter form, find the coefficient of $x^6$ in $(1+3x +3x^2 +x^3)^3$

If beads of a given color were $\texttt{identical}$, the generating function would simply be $(1+x+x^2+x^3)^3$
as  in  the FARIDABAD case where. e.g. you can't distinguish betweem the two $D's$ or two $A's$



Do you really need $x$ and $y$. It is a very elementary IIT-JEE problem.
There are broadly two cases if we follow the given specifications
Case 1:
We draw $2$ balls from $3$ boxes(one of each color) and $4$ balls from $1$ box(2R,2B or 3R,1B) which can be done in
$$\binom{4}{1}\left(\left(\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1}\right)^3\left(\binom{3}{2}\binom{2}{2}+\binom{3}{3}\binom{2}{1}\right)\right)=216\times20$$ where $\binom{4}{1}$ is the number of ways to select one box from which $4$ balls will be drawn.
Case 2:
We draw $2$ balls(1R,1B) from $2$ boxes and $3$ balls(2R,1B or 1R,2B) each from remaining $2$ boxes which can be done in $$\binom{4}{2}\left(\left(\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1}\right)^2\left(\binom{3}{2}\binom{2}{2}+\binom{3}{3}\binom{2}{1}\right)^2\right)=216\times81$$ where $\binom{4}{2}$ is the number of ways to select two boxes from which $2$ balls will be drawn.
So, required number of ways $$=216\times20+216\times81=216\times101=21816$$
As for $4$ letters from letters of the word FARIDABAD similar analysis does the trick.
Observe that we have
$3$ A's
$2$ D's
$1$ B
$1$ I
$1$ F
$1$ R
Number of selections can be categorized as
All letters different which can be done in $\binom{6}{4}=15$ ways
$2$ letters same and $2$ other different which can be done in $\binom{2}{1}\binom{5}{2}=20$ways
$2$ letters same and other $2$ letters also same which can be done in $\binom{2}{2}=1$way
$3$ letters same and $1$ letter different which can be done in $\binom{1}{1}\binom{5}{1}=5$ways
So required number of ways$=15+20+1+5=41$



Consider $4$ boxes, where each box contains $3$ red balls and $2$ blue balls. Assume that all $20$ balls are distinct. In how many different ways can $10$ balls be chosen from these $4$ boxes so that
from each box atleast one red ball and one blue ball are chosen?

Solution:
Required number of ways = coefficient of $x^2$+coefficient of $xy$+
coefficent of $y^2$ in $(3x+3x^2+x^3)^4(2y+y^2)$ and which is
$21816$.}


Actually, taking the coefficient of $x^2$ of $(3x+3x^2+x^3)^4(2x+x^2)$ already works. The motivation of this polynomial is the same motivation the polynomial you gave, $(3x+3x^2+x^3)^4(2x+x^2)$.


This is not an answer, please remove it.

I don't under stand what you mean by This is not an answer...

Would “Taking the coefficient of $x^6$ in $21816 x^6$ already works” be an answer?  No?  Then you understand why this is not an answer either.
